# openmp parallel recursive function in c

Tags: c, recursion, openmp, permutation

How do I parallelize, with openMP, the recursion below? Because I have a problem with my code that can be solved in this way. I got this code from the following site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Code:

```
// C program to print all permutations with duplicates allowed
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
This function takes three parameters:
1. String
2. Starting index of the string
3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
   int i;
   if (l == r)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
       for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
       {
          swap((a+l), (a+i));
          permute(a, l+1, r);
          swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
    char str[] = "ABC";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens unintentionally if you try the ways of parallelising loops according to  some openmp tutorial? Which ways did you try?  In which way did they fail? Did you read about nesting parallelising?

Comment: the tutorials I saw, do not lock loops that way, I tried to parallelize the permute function, however, it always used only thread 0 to do the recursion and did not split the task between the threads. I have to say that I'm a beginner in programming and I do not know how nesting parallelism works.

Comment: Please show how you "tried to parallelize the permute function" and explain how the result/behaviour is unsatisfying. Try to avoid the impression of just asking for code which does what you want.

Comment: I tried the form below. I do not know a strategy, using openmp, to parallelize this recursion. I do not want a ready code, just a strategy to parallelize because I could not break the recursion into two parts.

   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2){permute()str, 0, n-1);}

Comment: Please edit your question to add helpful information. Please take the [tour]. Please  read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways I can think of doing this. One is to parallelize over the permute function and the other is over the [rank](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Rank_of_a_permutation#C).

This answer uses the second method.  For `n = strlen(str)` the number of permutations (aka ranks) is `n!`.  E.g. for `str = "ABCD"` the number of ranks is `24`.  Here is one method to do this over rank (based on [this paper](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/RankPerm/RankPerm.html)):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SWAP(a,b) do{t=(a);(a)=(b);(b)=t;}while(0)

void get_permutation(int rank, int n, char *vec) {
    int t, q, r;
    if (n < 1) return;
    q = rank / n;
    r = rank % n;
    SWAP(vec[r], vec[n-1]);
    get_permutation(q, n-1, vec);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char a[5] = "ABCD", t[5];

  #pragma omp parallel for private(t) schedule(dynamic)
  for (int r = 0; r < 24; ++r) {
    strcpy(t, a);
    get_permutation(r, 4, t);
    #pragma omp critical
    printf("%3d: %s\n", r, t);
  }
}
```

As long as `get_permutation` is slower than the output (in this case `printf`) this method should win in performance.  I this will be true for a sufficiently large string length.

The output on my system is

```
  3: BCAD
  6: DABC
  7: CABD
  9: DACB
  8: BDCA
 10: BADC
 11: BACD
 13: CDAB
 14: DBAC
 15: CBAD
 16: DCBA
  1: DCAB
 17: ACDB
 19: ACBD
 20: DBCA
 21: ADCB
 22: ABDC
 23: ABCD
 12: CBDA
  0: BCDA
 18: ADBC
  4: CDBA
  2: BDAC
  5: CADB
```